# PHP: Inserting Values from the Form into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a `users` table in `mysql` from the terminal and I am trying to create simple task: insert values from the form. This is my `dbConfig file`

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pass", "testDB");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
?>
```

and This is my `Index.php` .

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="$1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>test</title>

    <?php
    include_once 'dbConfig.php';
    ?>

</head>
<body>
     <?php
    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
        VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["email"]."')";
    }

    ?>

    <form method="post"> 
    <label id="first"> First name:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="username"><br/>

    <label id="first">Password</label><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br/>

    <label id="first">Email</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br/>

    <button type="submit" name="save">save</button>
    <button type="submit" name="get">get</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

After hitting my save button, nothing happens, database is still empty. I tried `echo'ing` the `INSERT` query and it takes all values from the form as it is supposed to. After I try to check if this worked from terminal, I login into my `sql` try to return all data from users table and I get empty set.

Comment: use function mysqli_query to perform SQL query

Comment: Your code is only `echo`ing a SQL query...

Comment: You need to `mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);` the query. You are currently just `echo`ing the query, which basically just outputs it to the screen.

Comment: mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The following code just declares a string variable that contains a MySQL query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["email"]."')";
```

It does not execute the query. In order to do that you need to use some functions but let me explain something else first.

**NEVER TRUST USER INPUT**: You should never append user input (such as form input from `$_GET` or `$_POST`) **directly** to your query. Someone can carefully manipulate the input in such a way so that it can cause great damage to your database. That's called SQL Injection. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

To protect your script from such an attack you **must** use Prepared Statements. More on prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Include prepared statements to your code like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
    VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

Notice how the `?` are used as placeholders for the values. Next you should prepare the statement using `mysqli_prepare`:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
```

Then start binding the input variables to the prepared statement:

```
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
```

And finally execute the prepared statements. (This is where the actual insertion takes place)

```
$stmt->execute();
```

**NOTE** Although not part of the question, I strongly advice you to never store passwords in clear text. Instead you should use `password_hash` to store a hash of the password

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I will defenetly look into that, as this is my first attempt on PHP I'm focusing only on functionality, but I will try to improve in the future.

Comment: @notrealme if you're just getting started I would strongly suggest looking at PDO. It's much easier to use than mysqli, especially with prepared statements.

Comment: I tried this and got an error complaining that mysqli_prepare requires 2 parameters.

Comment: @dimlucas what is "sss" in parameters binding?

Comment: @A.Volg 's' stands for string. If one of the params was a number we would use 'd' to indicate a decimal

Comment: more info on parameter types (like 'sss' in the example above): https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems in your code.

1. No action found in form.
2. You have not executed the query **mysqli_query()**

**dbConfig.php**

```
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","testDB");

if(!$conn)
{
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

**index.php**

```
 include('dbConfig.php');

<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="description" content="$1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>test</title>


</head>
<body>

 <?php

  if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["username"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["email"]."')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post"> 
<label id="first"> First name:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="username"><br/>

<label id="first">Password</label><br/>
<input type="password" name="password"><br/>

<label id="first">Email</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="email"><br/>

<button type="submit" name="save">save</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```