# Trying to save user information, error

Tags: php

I am trying to save the information stored in the SQL but this error keeps coming out: **"Error Saving Data. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'company = 'GlobalTop Inc.' where regid = 1' at line 6"** What seems to be the error?

Here is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<?php
include "db.php";
$gresult = ''; //declare global variable



//Start of edit contact read
if(isset($_POST["action"]) and $_POST["action"]=="edit"){
            $id = (isset($_POST["ci"])? $_POST["ci"] : '');
            $sql = "select regid, regname,
                            address, phone,
                            email,company from tblregistrants
                            where regid = $id";

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

            if(!$result)
            {
                echo mysqli_error($link);
                exit();
            }

            $gresult = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            include 'update.php';
            exit();
}
//Insert or Update contact information
if(isset($_POST['action_type']))
{
        if ($_POST['action_type'] == 'add' or $_POST['action_type'] == 'edit')
        {
                //Sanitize the data and assign to variables
                $regid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['regid']));
                $regname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['regname']));
                $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
                $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['address']));         
                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['email']));
                $company = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, strip_tags($_POST['company']));

                if ($_POST['action_type'] == 'add')
                {
                    $sql = "insert into tblregistrants set
                                        name = '$regname',
                                        phone = '$phone',
                                        address = '$address',
                                        email = '$email'
                                        company = '$company'";
                }else{
                    $sql = "update tblregistrants set
                                        name = '$regname',
                                        phone = '$phone',
                                        address = '$address',
                                        email = '$email'
                                        company = '$company'
                                        where regid = $regid";
}


        if (!mysqli_query($link, $sql))
        {
            echo 'Error Saving Data. ' . mysqli_error($link);
            exit();
        }
    }
    header('Location: view.php');
    exit();
}

//Read registrants information from database : Stage 1
$sql = "select * from tblregistrants";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if(!$result)
{
    echo mysqli_error($link);
    exit();
}
//Loop through each row on array and store the data to $reg_list[] : Stage 2
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $reg_list[] = array('regid' => $rows['regid'],
    'regname' => $rows['regname'],
    'address' => $rows['address'],
    'phone' => $rows['phone'],
    'email' => $rows['email'],
    'company' => $rows['company']);
}
include 'view.php';
exit();

?>
```

Comment: You're missing many `,` in your query for example `email = '$email'`.

Comment: @Shanukk What are you talking about?

Comment: `$_POST["ci"]` is also open to sql injection.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com for more information about SQL injection & how to prevent them.

Comment: @Twinfriends mysql does not support stacked querys so dropping a table is not possible, but dumping it is. Especially with `mysqli_error` ;p

Comment: `or` is valid PHP but wrong in this case. You'll need to use `||` instead. (see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or). Looks like you are simply missing a quotation  `where regid = $regid"`. IMPORTANT: You're code is really not safe, you inject directly the data from your form in your SQL query, SQL Injection is really easy to do this way... Also it's not recommended to insert variables like that in a SQL array. Check this post for a better example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367992/php-inserting-values-from-the-form-into-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz its **mysql** error not **php** error

Comment: @B.Desai there are tons of php syntax error and you claim that this is not php error? way to go champ!

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz Have you read question properly? **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'company = 'GlobalTop Inc.** This is sql error not php

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `,` in both if and else  statement after `email = '$email'`

```
 if ($_POST['action_type'] == 'add')
                {
                    $sql = "insert into tblregistrants set
                                        name = '$regname',
                                        phone = '$phone',
                                        address = '$address',
                                        email = '$email', 
                                        company = '$company'";
                }else{
                    $sql = "update tblregistrants set
                                        name = '$regname',
                                        phone = '$phone',
                                        address = '$address',
                                        email = '$email',
                                        company = '$company'
                                        where regid = $regid";
}
```

Also use **Prepared statement** to prevent from SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

as Lawrence suggested you are missing , on your query
try this:

```
$sql = "insert into tblregistrants set
                                    name = '$regname',
                                    phone = '$phone',
                                    address = '$address',
                                    email = '$email',
                                    company = '$company'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this,

```
                      $sql = "update tblregistrants set
                                        name = '$regname',
                                        phone = '$phone',
                                        address = '$address',
                                        email = '$email',
                                        company = '$company'
                                        where regid = $regid";
```

To this

```
                            $sql = "update tblregistrants set
                                            name = '$regname',
                                            phone = '$phone',
                                            address = '$address',
                                            email = '$email',
                                            company = '$company'
                                            where regid = '$regid'";
```