# How to create a table?

Tags: mysql

I have been trying for a while to create a table but keep getting these errors.

my table is:
create table loginform
values('users','pin''8909')

5 errors were found during analysis.

1. > An opening bracket was expected. (near "VALUES" at position 24)
2. > At least one column definition was expected. (near " " at position 22)
3. > Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "'users'" at position 31)
4. > Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "'pin'" at position 40)
5. > Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "'8909'" at position 47)

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE loginform VALUES('users', 'pin', '8909')
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES('users', 'pin', '8909')' at line 2

Comment: You seem to be mixing Create table with an Insert statement. You need to first create the table where you define the columns. _Then_ you can do an insert statement. I would recommend you to do some proper research.

Comment: It is really hard to find a duplicate for such a basic task.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/37367992/2943403

Comment: The manual would be an excellent place to start

Answer (score 3):

This is the SQL format for creating a new table.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 datatype,
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
   ....
);
```

In your case,

```
CREATE TABLE loginform (
    id int,
    user varchar(255),
    ....
);
```

To insert data,

```
INSERT INTO loginform (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3);
```

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE` should not have any `VALUES` section. Refer to manual page to understand how to create tables and their columns. You've missed column structure section.

Probably, you should replace `CREATE TABLE` with `INSERT INTO` if you want to insert data:

`INSERT INTO loginform VALUES('users', 'pin', '8909');`

Answer (score 0):

To do it in php you have to do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    pin int(255) NOT NULL
);
```