# trying to import a 15k lines CSV to SQL via PHP but I get only 600-900 lines imported each time

Tags: php, sql, csv

This is my first post, I apologize in advance for my mistakes...

I'm trying to import a 15k lines csv file to SQL via PHP, but I get only 600-900 lines imported each time.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
    {
     $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];    
     if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
      { 
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
          while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',', '"')) !== FALSE)
           {
             $sql = "INSERT into testimport() 
             values ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."')";

              $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

              if(!isset($result))
              {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                window.location = \"readRecords.php\"
                </script>";    
              }
              else 
              {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                window.location = \"readRecords.php\"
                </script>";
              }
           }
        fclose($file);  
      }
    }
?>
```

Thanks so much for your help!!
Giorgio

Answer (score 0):

Before the `while` loop begins, add the following line of code:

`set_time_limit (300)`

it would set the time limit for a query to be executed to 5 mins (300 secs)

Comment: Thanks Dexter, I added the set_time_limit and now it uploads 8200 to 8400 rows in the first 20-30 seconds, but then it stops. Even if I set a time limit 300sec or 600sec, I always get max 8400 rows imported, which is much better than yesterday :-) , but still not the 15k rows that are stored in the csv file.  The fgetcsv() function works pretty well, I can echo all the 15k lines and perform math operations on all the 41 columns, but I still didn't succeed to import them ALL at once into the SQL table...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line before you call `fopen`

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
```

See james dot ellis at gmail dot com's comment on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

It is possible that you may have line endings that are encoded differently by a different OS. For example, Windows will be `\r\n` while Unix based systems use `\n`

which could result in some lines being concatenated together. For example,

```
Say,Something,Im<NEW_LINE_CHAR>
Giving,Up,On<NEW_LINE_CHAR>
```

If fgetcsv captures the end line character correctly, it would produce separate iterations of $getData as follows:

Iteration 1:

```
[0] => Say
[1] => Something
[2] => Im
```

Iteration 2:

```
[0] => Giving
[1] => Up
[2] => On
```

Whereas if it did not detect the endline character correctly, you would end up with both lines concatenated together. The line would then get parsed to a $getData array with 6 elements. The last three would be ignored by the script which writes only positions 0,1 and 2 to the SQL insertion script.

Iteration 1:

```
[0] => Say
[1] => Something
[2] => Im<NEW_LINE_CHAR>
[3] => Giving (Ignored)
[4] => Up (Ignored)
[5] => On<NEW_LINE_CHAR>(Ignored)
```

Lastly, you may want to avoid writing SQL code where you are appending unverified Strings to your Insertion code. It is dangerous and really prone to injection attacks. Highly recommend you look into using Prepared Statements which would look something like this:

```
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($getData[0], $getData[1],$getData[2]);
    $sql = "INSERT into testimport() values (?,?,?)";
```

See [PHP: Inserting Values from the Form into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367992/php-inserting-values-from-the-form-into-mysql) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Daryl! In my specific case the csv file is always properly formatted as it is automatically generated by another server. I combined the second part of your recommendations (binding function) with @dexter 's recommendation (timeout of 45 sec) and... it works!! :-) Thank you very much!!  What a great Team work!! I will post below the code that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @dexter and @Daryl !

I combined your recommendations and the process now works perfectly!

I can import 15k records of 41 columns in 28 seconds and 30k records in 60 seconds! Amazing! Now, I need to automate it, but that's another sory :-)

This is my final code:

```
include('dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
     $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];    
     if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
     {
        ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE); 
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");

          set_time_limit (45);
          while ($getData = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',', '"'))
           {
              $sql = "INSERT INTO testimport 
                    ( 
                      id_record,panel_number,machine_number,id_internal_code,
                      id_number,tot_production,waiting_time,operation_length,
                      avg_flow,max_flow,flow_15,flow_30,flow_60,flow_120,
                      avg_temp,max_temp,avg_cond,max_cond,m_detach,m_input,
                      m_quantity,m_input_nc,max_time,m_operation,m_sep_,
                      a_no_flow,a_conductivity,a_low_prod,a_kick_off,
                      a_temperature,prod_2min,low_flow_time,
                      50char_graph_data,data_enter,data_start,data_end,
                      data_exit,preparation_time,nr_session,perc_2min,
                      perc_low_flow
                    ) 

                    VALUES 
                     (
                        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
                     )"; 

                   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);

                   $stmt->bind_param
                   (    "sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
                        $getData[0],  $getData[1],  $getData[2],  $getData[3], 
                        $getData[4],  $getData[5],  $getData[6],  $getData[7],  
                        $getData[8],  $getData[9],  $getData[10], $getData[11], 
                        $getData[12], $getData[13], $getData[14], $getData[15], 
                        $getData[16], $getData[17], $getData[18], $getData[19],
                        $getData[20], $getData[21], $getData[22], $getData[23], 
                        $getData[24], $getData[25], $getData[26], $getData[27], 
                        $getData[28], $getData[29], $getData[30], $getData[31], 
                        $getData[32], $getData[33], $getData[34], $getData[35], 
                        $getData[36], $getData[37], $getData[38], $getData[39],
                        $getData[40]
                   );

                   $sql = "INSERT into testimport() 
                   values 
                   (
                      ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                      ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
                    )";

               $stmt->execute();
           }

        fclose($file);  
        mysqli_close($conn);
     }
}
```